# Openshift - Environment Variable - Integer/Float

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise

How do I set an integer or float value to the deployment config environment variable or in a configmap. I am getting the

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${KEYCLOAK_PORT_VAR}".
```

Comment: The form ``${KEYCLOAK_PORT_VAR}`` is usually used in a template. That it is passed through as is indicates that there wasn't actually a template parameter called ``KEYCLOAK_PORT_VAR``. How did you deploy this in the first place.

Comment: oc new-build --name=idpjenkins --docker-image=himanshumps/idp_jenkins:latest --binary=true -l app=idpjenkins
    oc new-app idpjenkins -e JENKINS_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/ -e KEYCLOAK_PORT_VAR=80 --allow-missing-imagestream-tags  -l app=idpjenkins
    oc start-build idpjenkins --from-archive="../jenkins/jenkins.tar"